# Python saves only one row of data

Tags: python, xpath

```
def get_user_data(self,start_url):
    html = self.session.get(url=start_url,headers=self.headers,cookies=self.cookies).content
    selector = etree.fromstring(html,etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
    all_user = selector.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"c") and contains(@id,"M")]')
    for i in all_user:
        user_id = i.xpath('./div[1]/a[@class="nk"]/@href')[0]
        content = i.xpath('./div[1]/span[1]')[0]
        contents = content.xpath('string(.)')
        times = i.xpath('./div/span[@class="ct"]/text()')[0]
        if len(i.xpath('./div[3]')):
            imgages = i.xpath('./div[2]/a/img/@src')
            praise_num = i.xpath('./div[3]/a[2]/text()')
            transmit_num = i.xpath('./div[3]/a[3]/text()')
        elif len(i.xpath('./div[2]')):
            imgages = i.xpath('./div[2]/a/img/@src')
            praise_num = i.xpath('./div[2]/a[3]/text()')
            transmit_num = i.xpath('./div[2]/a[4]/text()')
        else :
            imgages = ''
            praise_num = i.xpath('./div[1]/a[2]/text()')
            transmit_num = i.xpath('./div[1]/a[3]/text()')
        try:
            if re.search('from',times.encode().decode('utf-8')):
                month_day, time, device = times.split(maxsplit=2)
                self.data['mobile_phone'] = device
            else:
                time,device = times.split(maxsplit=1)
                self.data['month_day'] = ''
            self.data['create_time'] = month_day + ' ' + time
        except Exception as e:
            print('failure：',e)
        self.data['crawl_time'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.data['user_id'] = user_id
        self.data['contents'] = contents.encode().decode('utf-8').replace('\u200b','')
        self.data['imgages'] = imgages
        self.data['praise_num'] = praise_num
        self.data['transmit_num'] = transmit_num
    with open('a.txt','a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(self.data)+'\n')
```

I try to grab every page of data and save it to data.But I wrote it wrong, because I saved only one piece of data on each page in 'a.txt'.So how do I write to save every page of data correctly in 'a.txt'?

Answer (score 0):

Write operation is outside the for loop thats why it is only adding last iteration data to file

```
with open('a.txt','a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(self.data)+'\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

You're overwriting the various values in `self.data` in every iteration of the loop.

Instead, `self.data` should be a list. You should create a new dictionary in each iteration and append it to the data at the end.

```
self.data = []
for i in all_user:
    values = {}
    ...
    values['crawl_time'] = ...
    values['user_id'] = ...
    ...
    self.data.append(values)
```